# Loops - causing ultimate confusion

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Firstly, apologies I do like to try and get some sort of solution sorted but, on this occasion I have do so much research on this that I have talked myself into the deepest state of confusion.
Second, I can't seem to attach the files so I have attached images of the two sheets examples and then an image of how the results should pull through.

Sheet 1 is a list of orders (column A), a list of products (D) and the total number of units that are required, by the business to fulfil that order and all above it.
Sheet 2 is a list of all inbound stock with product code in (A), quantity inbound (D) and the date it is due in (C)

The loop needs to work through column D, take that product code and then the total units required from column F.
It then needs to find the corresponding product in sheet 2 column A. Workout the correct line that will deliver enough units and take the date from column C and return to sheet 1 column G

In the 3rd attachment is the picture example

BRT8951 does not require any stock and therefore no date is returned
BSN2723 required 164 units. The 4 units is insufficient but, the 184 units is sufficient so it return 04/04/2041.
BSS3442 needs 180 and the 424 is more than enough to cover this so it return 04/04/2042.
BSX8606 need 446 units but, the max on order is 435 so that date returned is 04/04/2049 and the comment of "insufficient stock" is inserted. If it is possible to return that 435 units will be allocated then amazing but, this is just an added bonus.
BTH2279 - all stock is absorbed by the previous order so no date is returned and the "insufficient stock" comment is returned

I really, really hope that makes sense and that someone can help me.

Thank you so much

[image]

[image]

Comment: quantity inbound (D)  ? It looks like col B is quantity recieved, D is total stock holding.

Comment: D is the cumulative qty of POs. So for example the 424 is made up of po's 1,2 and 3. If an order was 424 units it would need the 4 units from PO 1, the 180 units from PO 2 and the full 240 units from PO 3 and would take the PO date from the 3rd and final PO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary` to match product ID's and `Collections` to hold the row number on sheet2 for the deliveries of that product.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub process()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsOrder As Worksheet, wsDeliv As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim qu As Single, z As Single, t as Single
    Dim iLastRow As Long, sID As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long
    Dim ar, col As Collection, dt As Date
  
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsOrder = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set wsDeliv = wb.Sheets(2)

    ' copy deliv data to array
    With wsDeliv
        i = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        ar = .Range("A1:E" & i).Value2
    End With

    ' use dict to match orders to deliv
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 2 To UBound(ar)
        sID = Trim(ar(i, 1)) ' Col A
        If Not dict.exists(sID) Then
            dict.Add sID, New Collection
        End If
        dict(sID).Add i, CStr(i)
    Next
 
    ' match orders
    With wsOrder
        iLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
        For i = 2 To iLastRow
            sID = Trim(.Cells(i, "D"))
            qu = .Cells(i, "F")

            If qu > 0 And dict.exists(sID) Then
                z = 0 ' stock
                t = 0 ' allocated
                For j = 1 To dict(sID).Count ' deliveries
                    r = dict(sID).Item(j) ' row
                    z = z + ar(r, 2) ' increase stock available
                    dt = ar(r, 3)
                    If qu <= z Then
                        .Cells(i, "G") = dt
                        .Cells(i, "H") = "OK avail = " & z
                        ar(r, 2) = t + ar(r, 2) - qu ' revise stock level
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        t = t + ar(r, 2)
                        ar(r, 2) = 0
                    End If
                Next

                ' any qu not fulfilled ?
                If qu > 0 Then
                     .Cells(i, "G") = dt
                     .Cells(i, "H") = "insufficent stock - max = " & z
                End If
            Else
                ' no delivery found
                If qu > 0 Then
                    .Cells(i, "H") = "No match for '" & sID & "'"
                End If
            End If
       Next
   End With

   MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry I haven't replied sooner. I will give this a try now and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Incredible - it works. You, my friend, are a genius. Thank you